# What are the repercussions for a woman who remains unmarried lifelong?

Tags: marriage, women, sin

If a woman remains unmarried all her life...

- Is she sent to Hell?
- Who is considered the sinner? She, her father, or someone else?
- If she is sent to Heaven, then on what grounds? She did not even fulfilled her Pativrata dharma. Her primary dharma in life is only Pativrata dharma and she did not fulfill it then how she goes to heaven?
  Also there is no example of a Unmarried woman in scriptures. Even Mirabai and Radhaji were asked to get married by Lord himself.

Answer (score 0):

Unmarried women as such never go to Hell. A woman birth is always sacred.  There are no such examples in Scriptures. But, there is a problem for female born from ages till present millenium.

KULAKSHAYAM : Unmarried women when attacked by invaders or captured by wars have to undergo a "slavery of sins" due to tyranny from overpowering groups for desire, greed of expansion of territory and slave subordinates.

Due to this reason, females were either forced into marriages(good path if proper rule in territory) or irresponsibilty (enslaved for desire if tertitory invaded). They were helpless.

Females are attractive in humans than males due to which both invasion sins and joy of rule impacts them to greater extent. Those males who did these sins may definitely reach Hell but not females as such. May be their offsprings can reach hell.

Examples: Sisupaalaa's parents were good, but Sisupaalaa reached hell for always abusing God's glorious names for his personal mental pain.

Comment: But why will she be sent to Heaven if she did not even follower her Pativrata dharma as she doesn't even have husband?  And there is no example of a Unmarried woman in scriptures. Even Mirabai and Radhaji were asked to get married by Lord himself.